# Mubaaaraah divorce

Tags: talaq, iddah

I am separated from husband from 2017 Jan to uptonow.we had no connection between us ..and we both had mubaraah divorce last Friday..what I want to know is since  We were separated on bed for 1 year am I need to follow Iddah

Answer (score -1):

I hope this explanations will help answering your question. Just click [here](https://www.islamqa.info/en/12667) and read them. Salaam!

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is strongly suggested](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) that you include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It is about talaq ..I am asking about mubaraah

Comment: And also I separated on bed for one year before mubaraah divorce. Due to same am I need to follow talaaq?

Comment: And also I separated on bed for one year before mubaraah divorce. Due to same am I need to follow iddah?